# Laravel OAUTH: Restrict users from requesting any scope they want

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-middleware, scopes

When requesting an OAUTH Grant Password token, the user can specify his desired scope. How can one prevent a regular user from requesting and admin scope?

The code exemplifies a malicious request that asks for an admin scope, although he shouldn't have accesss to it.

```
curl -X POST \
    http://a.myapiserver.com/api/oauth/token \
    -F grant_type=password \
    -F client_id=2 \
    -F client_secret=PpMrx32Zow5OcQf491GXXT0dlEzMNuYHt6fe4Wdy \
    -F username=regularuser \
    -F password=strongpasss \
    -F scope=admin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved by adding a middleware ScopeLogic and adding it to the passport::routes.

found the solution here: https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/259c0dd